# Migrating from 32 bit using pg_basebackup

Tags: postgresql, migration, postgresql-9.2, backup, pg-basebackup

Has anyone migrated a 32 bit postgres 9.2 database to a 64 bit postgres 9.2?

I'm trying to use pg_basebackup but I'm not sure whether this is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

`pg_basebackup` is *not* the right approach. It won't work, because the 32-bit and 64-bit data directories are not compatible.

You will have to dump and reload using `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`, plus a `pg_dumpall --globals-only` restored via `psql` for user accounts etc.